# Actual components are not displayed after filtering catalog in Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3

There is an array catalog which is displayed onto the page. After filtering, only the number of filtered products is displayed correctly, but the components do not change their content

Video showing the problem: [video](https://youtu.be/ntgL8QWJBlA)

```
<h2 class="typical-title">Catalog</h2>
    <section v-if="!isLoading" class="typical-section">
        <div v-if="sorting_items.size > 0" class="catalog-sorting">
            <a v-for="(item, key) in sorting_items" :key="key" @click.prevent="sortingSwith(item)" href=""
                class="catalog-sorting-link">{{ item }}</a>
        </div>
        <div v-if="catalog.length > 0" class="catalog-content">
            <div class="catalog-content-item">
                <CatalogItem v-for="item in catalog" :content=item />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div v-else>
            <p class="catalog-empty-title">Catalog is empty</p>
            <a href="/#contacts" class="catalog-empty-link">Contact us</a>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="typical-section" v-else>
        <div class="loader">Loading</div>
    </section>
```

I have this code now

```
export default {
    components: {
        CatalogItem
    },
    data() {
        return {
            isLoading: true,
            catalog_raw: [],
            choosen_type: null,
            sorting_items: new Set([]),
            isEnd: false,
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.fetchCatalog()
    },
    methods: {
        fetchCatalog() {
            axios.get(`${API_URL}/catalog`).then(result => {
                if (result.data.status === 200) {
                    this.catalog_raw = result.data.content
                    for (let i = 0; i < this.catalog_raw.length; i++) {
                        this.sorting_items.add(this.catalog_raw[i].product_type)
                    }
                } else {
                    console.error(result.data.title)
                }
                this.isLoading = false
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error(error)
                this.isLoading = false
            })
        },
        sortingSwith(type) {
            this.choosen_type = type
        },
    },
    computed: {
        catalog() {
            return this.catalog_raw.filter(item => {
                if (this.choosen_type === null) {
                    return item
                } else {
                    if (item.product_type === this.choosen_type) {
                        return item
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

What could be the problem? Thanks in advance for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really have a [key](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-attributes.html#key) when using `v-for`, especially for lists where the order of items can change.  A unique key helps Vue understand how to properly diff a changing list of components.  Try using the following:

```html
<CatalogItem v-for="item in catalog" :key="item.product_id" :content="item" />
```